# Unable to set drawing modes in Drawing Control Options in GWT Google maps

Tags: arrays, google-maps, gwt, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I am creating a GWT application where in only the user should be able to draw only rectangle on the map. So I would like to display only the hand icon and the rectangle icon the drawing control bar. By default all the controls will be displayed.

I have created a JsArray and pushed the OverlayType.RECTANGLE in the array and set the drawing modes using the below code.

```
DrawingControlOptions drawingControlOptions = DrawingControlOptions.create();
    drawingControlOptions.setPosition(ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER);
JsArray<OverlayType> drawingModes = (JsArray<OverlayType>) OverlayType.createArray();
    drawingModes.push(OverlayType.RECTANGLE);
    drawingControlOptions.setDrawingModes(drawingModes);
```

[image]

But I am not see the rectangle icon only the HAND icon is being displayed.

Kindly let me know if I have set the drawing modes incorrectly.
Any Help is appreciated.
Thanks!!!

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find something to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The same problem just happened to me. I'm pretty sure that the lib is broken. Here is a workaround I've used:

```
  private native DrawingControlOptions createDrawingControlOptions() /*-{
    return {
      drawingModes: ['rectangle']
    }
  }-*/;
```